# Ampersand entity marked red in HTML source page (Firefox)

Tags: html, firefox

```
<a href="foo&bar">
```

The ampersand in above HTML is marked bold red in the view-source page in Firefox and the tool-tip suggests encoding the ampersand as *&amp;*

But when I write this:

```
<a href="foo&amp;bar">
```

The "&amp;" string is still red, just not bolded. There is no tool-tip either. Why is it colored red? Is there some error?

Using Firefox 62.0 on Windows.

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [Submit a bug report to mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1188220) (It's not a *bug* as such but the GUI can be improved)

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it colored red? Is there some error?

Nope, that's just how character references are highlighted in Firefox's source viewer. The color is actually somewhat subdued, but I can see how it might be confusing.

You'll know if it's a parse error or invalid character reference if it's red *and* bold. In your example, the `<html>` start tag is also erroneous, as it's not being preceded by a DOCTYPE marker.